# Почему при сложении byte не переполняется?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

Есть вот такой очень простой код.

```
using System;

class Test
{       
    static void Main()
    {
        byte x = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        byte y = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
    }
}
```

При вводе 123 и 221 выводит 344. Но ведь должно было произойти переполнение, почему оно не произошло? Почему не вывело 344 - 255 = 89?

Comment: Потому что это C# ... У этого языка девиз такой - преобразуй всё во всё, читайте спецификацию.

Comment: Если вы в студии наведете курсор на знак `+` между x и y, то увидите всплывающую подсказку `int int.operator +(int left, int right)`, т. е. они перед сложением приводятся в int и результат получается тоже в int. Для int, естественно переполнения тут нет.

Comment: Если явно преобразовать ответ в byte, то всё получится логично. Проблема кроется в неявном приведении к int.
Console.WriteLine((byte)(x + y));

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Отличный вопрос!

Согласно [спецификации языка](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1195-addition-operator), определены следующие операторы числового сложения:

```
int operator +(int x, int y);
uint operator +(uint x, uint y);
long operator +(long x, long y);
ulong operator +(ulong x, ulong y);

float operator +(float x, float y);
double operator +(double x, double y);

decimal operator +(decimal x, decimal y);
```

Сложение байтов не определено. Таким образом, язык применяет конверсию, и превращает `byte` в `int`, чтобы использовать `int operator +(int x, int y);`.

Почему выбирается именно перегрузка с `int`, а не, скажем, с `uint`? Обратимся снова к спецификации.

Правила конверсии описаны [здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11473-binary-numeric-promotions) (перевод мой):

> Расширение типов для бинарных операторов состоит в применении следующих правил в том порядке, в каком они специфицированы тут:
>
> - Если хотя бы один из операндов имеет тип `decimal`, другой операнд преобразуется в тип `decimal`, или возникает ошибка времени привязки типов, если тип другого операнда — `float` или `double`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `double`, другой операнд преобразуется в `double`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `float`, другой операнд преобразуется в `float`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `ulong`, другой операнд преобразуется в `ulong`, или возникает ошибка времени привязки типов если другой операнд имеет тип `sbyte`, `short`, `int` или `long`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `long`, другой операнд преобразуется в `long`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `uint` и тип другого операнда `sbyte`, `short` или `int`, оба операнда преобразуются в `long`.
> - Иначе, если тип хотя бы одного из операндов `uint`, другой операнд преобразуется в `uint`.
> - Иначе оба операнда преобразуются в `int`.

В нашем случае работает последний пункт, остальные неприменимы. Значения преобразуются в `int` *до* сложения, и тип результата — `int`.

Comment: Вот это больше похоже на правду.

Comment: Я бы добавил что `WriteLine(int)` существует а `WriteLine(byte)` нет, поэтому это сужает выбор преобразований. Возможно там где есть такая перезагрузка - будет преобразование назад.

Comment: @nick_n_a: Насколько я понимаю, в этой точке ожидаемый тип не играет роли.

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что результат сложения `byte` + `byte` вовсе не обязан иметь тип `byte`.

На самом деле, результат сложения имеет тип `int`, в который можно запросто поместить число `334`.

А проверить это утверждение можно вот так:

```
using System;

class Test
{       
    static void Main()
    {
        byte x = 123;
        byte y = 221;
        byte z = x + y;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

Приведет к ошибке:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Не понятно почему не обязан. Решение я бы сократил в одну строчку.

Comment: https://ideone.com/JU08im - да :) Хотя странно. Вроде другие языки в таком случае кастят сами.

Comment: @nick_n_a,  `byte` + `byte` = `int`. Все дело в спецификации языка :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Не кастит потому что нет перезагрузки WriteLine(byte)

Comment: Нет такого неявного преобразования int в byte, поэтому только явно надо кастовать

Comment: @Андрей, ага, мой пример как раз и направлен на то, чтобы показать, что `byte` + `byte` = `int`.

Comment: @nick_n_a потому что создатели языка так решили. На самом деле, эта фича унаследована из Java.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, [да](https://ideone.com/R0JK4w), это я `+` с `+=` перепутал - там можно.