# Почему нельзя сложить в C# byte + byte?

Tags: c#

Я знаю что нужно выполнить преобразование типов, но хотел бы разобраться в механизме.
Почему этот код выдает ошибку?

```
byte a = 2;

byte b = a + 2; // ошибка
```

Comment: потому что `2` - это int

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему при сложении byte не переполняется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711854/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-byte-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что операции с байтами возвращают в результате `int`. Это не совсем очевидно на первый взгляд, но имеет смысл. Дело в том, что `byte` - довольно маленькая величина (от 0 до 255), и во многих случаях в результате арифметических операций с двумя байтовыми переменными, возникает переполнение, благодаря чему результат не поместился бы в переменную типа `byte`. Это явно не очень ожидаемое поведение (например при сложении 200 и 60 получилось бы не 260, ка можно было бы ожидать, а 4),  поэтому было решено, что `byte + byte = int`

Comment: >>например при сложении 200 и 60 получилось бы<< Интересно, а как принудить получать 4? Или, всё равно придётся добавлять операцию %256?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, здесь скорее `byte + int = int`.

Comment: @VladD, может закроешь дубликатом? мне кажется в том вопросе хорошее пояснение в ответе

Comment: @Grundy: Я немного не уверен: пояснение там к этому вопросу подходит, но сам вопрос там немного другой: там о преобразовании типов операндов, а тут о ошибке из-за неправильного типа результата. Не хватает одного шага: понять, что ошибка из-за того, что тип результата `int`. А вот почему именно он `int`, на это отвечает тот, другой вопрос.

Comment: @test123 можно сделать `byte a = 200; byte c = (byte)(a + 60);`

Comment: @Regent, вот оно как! А как дела обстоят с литералами? Есть возможность как то явно указать байт-число? Хочется просто избавиться от этих приведений...

Comment: @test123 использование бинарного литерала `0b111100` вместо `60` ситуацию не улучшит - приведение всё равно будет нужно при сложении с переменной. Сумму двух бинарных литералов, если она меньше 256, приводить не нужно (как, собственно, и если бы вместо бинарных были обычные), но и толку от такой суммы мало. Так что никаких хитрых вариантов предложить не могу.

Comment: Надо же было так недалёко "решить"! Любой нормальный программист при сложении в пределах байта 200 и 60 никак не ожидает получить 260! ЯП для домохозяек делают?

Comment: @Isaev: Вы серьёзно ожидаете от сложения 200 и 60 получить не 260?

Comment: @VladD, Вы серьёзно ожидание получить 260, зная, что в байт больше 255 не вылезает?

Comment: @Isaev: Я серьёзно ожидаю от хорошего высокоуровневого языка программирования (не ассемблера и не «портабельного ассемблера») не заставлять меня думать о степенях двойки. Если сложение байт не обязательно влазит в байт, значит, сумма байт не имеет права быть байтом. Я бы ожидал не неявного взятия по модулю 256, а явного, запрошенного программистом (хотя бы потому, что это в большинстве случаев не ожидается программистом).

Comment: @Isaev: Язык должен вести себя интуитивно. У программистов есть более серьёзные и сложные задачи, чем помнить о странных и нелепых особенностях языка.

Comment: @VladD, для этого есть множество не типизированных языков типа бейсика. А если уж язык изначально задуман типизированным, и программистом задан нужный ему тип, компилятор уж точно не должен заниматься таким произволом.

Comment: @Isaev: Почему вдруг нетипизированный? Почему вы считаете, что byte + byte обязательно должно быть byte'ом? Наоборот, строго типизированный подход делает byte + byte int'ом, так что язык ведёт себя ожидаемым образом без потери типобезопасности. А вот решение в С и C++ кажется мне очень неинтуитивным и спорным.

Comment: @VladD, больше всего от вас не ожидал рассуждений в таком ключе. Ну да ладно, дело вкуса... Мне это очень не привычно, т.к. вырос на ассемблере ещё со времён спектрума. Для меня такие "непредсказуемые" манипуляции компилятора над моими типами - ставить палки в колёса программисту. С другой стороны на спектруме был бейсик, где не было привязки к типам. После него Паскаль был очень непривычным)

Comment: @Isaev: В том-то и дело, что мы слишком привыкли к влиянию ассемблера в наших языках программирования. И это неправильно, т. к. хорошая архитектура процессора вовсе не означает хорошей архитектуры языка. У процессора цель быть эффективным и предоставлять возможность кодировать различные операции, а у языка цель — отсутствие неожиданностей и эффективность разработки. Ну и я всегда предпочитаю явное преобразование неявному. Если мне нужно отбросить верхний байт результата, лучше сделать это явно (`(a + b) % 256` или `(byte)(a + b)`), чем разрешать языку терять кусок результата неявно.