# Почему если указыватьсокращенную форму присваивания, то явное приведение не нужно?

Tags: c#

Данная форма записи автоматически преобразовывает.

```
byte a = 10, b = 5;
a+=b;
```

А вот здесь нужно явно указывать преобразование

```
byte a = 10, b = 5;
a = (byte) a+b
```

Почему так?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726046/220553